# External table snowflake refresh issue /questions / confirmation / with external stage on azure plateform

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for small help in below snowflake scenario.

Going by snowflake official documentation its clear that external tables needs to refresh at least once(auto or manual) so that its setup is completed and query should be able to fetch rows.

What happens in case where underline path and filenames is not changing, but we are replacing the file with new data. Whether new data will be available if we query the external table from snowflake
without event grid setup (which perform refresh) or without performing manual refresh. ?

ex . some_external_path/location/file_with_data.csv

Comment: I am facing same issue. Though the file name is same and if the data gets refreshed in the file, it is not reflecting when we query the external table. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger a refresh automatically when the external files change. Snowflake documentation covering this process is here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-azure.html

Alternatively, if you just want to run the refresh on a schedule you could set up a Snowflake task to execute an ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE … REFRESH statement